# Show files larger in sidebar in PhpStorm

Tags: ide, phpstorm

I have a question about the view of files in the sidebar of PhpStorm. I often give lessons about Laravel framework. Then I use PhpStorm to code some examples. I always change the font-size in `Preferences > Editor > Colors & Fonts > Font`.

But how can I change the size of folders and files in my sidebar?

[image]

Comment: Do not know what exactly you have in mind .. but try `View | Enter Presentation Mode` -- it will make the text large and remove lots of panels from the screen (which you can bring back manually).